# Uknown column error i have tired multpul things

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting a Unknown column error and i cant seem to find a topic that seems to help me.. here the code but when i seem to remove the WHERE username = $user in the $query or replace $user with a quote it seems to work just fine. (FYI Im like a total noob at php)

```
<?PHP

$id = "";
$username = "";
$email = "";
$nick = "";
$isMod = "";
$rank = "";
$joinDate = "";
$ip = "";
$coins = "";
$curHead = "";
$curFace = "";
$curNeck = "";
$curBody = "";
$curHands = "";
$curFeet = "";
$curPhoto = "";
$curFlag = "";
$curColor = "";

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("opencp", $db);

$user = $_GET['user'];

$query = "SELECT * from game_users WHERE username = ". $user. "";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error());

}

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"\n";
echo "<products>\n";

while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<item>" . $line['id'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['username'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['email'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['nickname'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['ismoderator'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['rank'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['joindate'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['ips'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['coins'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curhead'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curface'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curneck'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curbody'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curhands'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curfeet'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curphoto'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['curflag'] . "</item>\n";
echo "<item>" . $line['colour'] . "</item>\n";

}

echo "</products>";

mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to,

```
$query = "SELECT * from game_users WHERE username = '". $user ."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

You should start with [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

username is a string so it should be in single quotes.

```
$user = $_GET['user'];  
$query = "SELECT * from game_users WHERE username = '". $user. "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple answers here already but I thought I'd point out that since your string is in double quotes you can make it less confusing by not using the concatenation (period) style:

```
$query = "SELECT * from game_users WHERE username = '$user ' ";
```

Variables are replaced inside double quotes in php, but not within single quoted strings.